# Need help passing variables and labeling JPanel

Tags: java, swing, global-variables, jpanel, joptionpane

Ive been going around with this for awhile and I am getting more confused.  There's a couple things I want to accomplish:

1. add 2 labels to JTextField 1.  The first asking them to enter an email.  The second indicating that the @address.com is already entered for them.
2. I am confused how to pass the String variables and maybe I should just have one method?

   ```
   import javax.swing.*;
   import java.awt.*;

   public class Email {

       public static void main(String[] args) {    //main method

           //get user input
           JPanel panel = new JPanel();  //create new JPanel

           JTextField field1 = new JTextField(20);  //create a field for email and show 20 characters
           panel.add(field1);

           JTextField field2 = new JTextField(6); //create a field for grade and show to 6 characters
           panel.add(field2);

           int iValue = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (
           null,
           panel,
           "Please enter students email adress and test grade",
           JOptionPane.OK_OPTION); //create button in panel

           if (iValue == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {

               //capture email address as String
               String sEmail = field1.getText() + "@address.com"; 

               //capture numerical grade input and convert it to a float    
               float fGrade = Float.parseFloat(field2.getText());
           }
       } //end main


       public void convertGrades(float fGrade) {

           /***"shortcut if" grade conversion***********
           String sLetterGrade =    (fGrade >= 97) ? "A+" :
           (fGrade >= 94) ? "A" :
           (fGrade >= 90) ? "A-" :
           (fGrade >= 87) ? "B+" : 
           (fGrade >= 84) ? "B" :
           (fGrade >= 80) ? "B-" :
           (fGrade >= 77) ? "C+" :
           (fGrade >= 74) ? "C" :
           (fGrade >= 70) ? "C-" :
           (fGrade >= 67) ? "D+" :
           (fGrade >= 64) ? "D" :
           (fGrade >= 60) ? "D-" : "F";
           *************************************************************************/


           //experimental grade conversion
           // Determine letter grade
           String sAlphaGrade =    (fGrade >= 90) ? "A" :
           (fGrade >= 80) ? "B" :
           (fGrade >= 70) ? "C" :
           (fGrade >= 60) ? "D" : "F";
           //determine + or -
           if (fGrade >= 60) {
               float fGradeModifier = (fGrade % 10); 
               String sAlphaModifier = (fGradeModifier >= 7) ? "+" :
               (fGradeModifier >= 4)? "" : "-";

               //concatenate letter grade and modifier
               String sLetterGrade = sAlphaGrade + sAlphaModifier;

           } // end if


           String sResults =    getInput.sEmail  + "\n" +
           sMessage + "\n" +
           "your test score is: " + fGrade + "\n" + 
           "your letter grade is: " + sLetterGrade;


           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sOutput,"Email and Grade",
           JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

       } //end convertGrades
   } //end class Email
   ```

Comment: PLEASE format the code in your question.

Comment: thanks Ali I am trying to format the code better now

Comment: What are `sMessage` and `sOutput`? I do not see them declared anywhere.

Comment: Do you want to have a JLabel by field2 as well to ask for entry of grade?

Answer (score 2):

Your code has some issues with where you declare and access variables. `sMessage` and `sOutput` are never declared or given values anywhere. Also, you try to access `sEmail` in the `convertGrades` method when it has been declared in `main`, and try to access `sLetterGrade` outside of the `if` block it was declared in.

If you want to use `sEmail` in your `convertGrades` method, you will need to pass it to the method when you call it. `sLetterGrade` must be declared outside of the `if` block to be used later on. Also, you never actually call `convertGrades` from your `main` method, so none of that code will execute.

To label your `JTextField`, I recommend putting all of the labels and the field in a [`Box`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html). This will ensure that they all stay together in the proper order.

Here is your code edited to include all of these changes:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class Email {

        public static void main(String[] args) {    //main method

            //get user input
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();  //create new JPanel


            Box field1Box = Box.createHorizontalBox(); // Box to hold field1 and its labels
            field1Box.add(new JLabel("Enter email: ")); // JLabels can be added directly; we don't need to keep a reference
            JTextField field1 = new JTextField(20);  //create a field for email and show 20 characters
            field1Box.add(field1);
            field1Box.add(new JLabel("@address.com"));
            panel.add(field1Box); // Adds the Box containing field1 and the two labels to panel


            JTextField field2 = new JTextField(6); //create a field for grade and show to 6 characters
            panel.add(field2);

            int iValue = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (
            null,
            panel,
            "Please enter student's email adress and test grade",
            JOptionPane.OK_OPTION); //create button in panel

            if (iValue == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {

                //capture email address as String
                String sEmail = field1.getText() + "@address.com"; 

                //capture numerical grade input and convert it to a float    
                float fGrade = Float.parseFloat(field2.getText());

                //call convertGrades to display the results
                convertGrades(fGrade, sEmail);
            }
        } //end main


        // convertGrades must be static to be called from main
        public static void convertGrades(float fGrade, String sEmail) {

            /***"shortcut if" grade conversion***********
            String sLetterGrade =    (fGrade >= 97) ? "A+" :
            (fGrade >= 94) ? "A" :
            (fGrade >= 90) ? "A-" :
            (fGrade >= 87) ? "B+" : 
            (fGrade >= 84) ? "B" :
            (fGrade >= 80) ? "B-" :
            (fGrade >= 77) ? "C+" :
            (fGrade >= 74) ? "C" :
            (fGrade >= 70) ? "C-" :
            (fGrade >= 67) ? "D+" :
            (fGrade >= 64) ? "D" :
            (fGrade >= 60) ? "D-" : "F";
            *************************************************************************/


            //experimental grade conversion
            // Determine letter grade
            String sAlphaGrade =    (fGrade >= 90) ? "A" :
            (fGrade >= 80) ? "B" :
            (fGrade >= 70) ? "C" :
            (fGrade >= 60) ? "D" : "F";
            String sLetterGrade; // This needs to be visible outside of the if
            //determine + or -
            if (fGrade >= 60) {
                float fGradeModifier = (fGrade % 10); 
                String sAlphaModifier = (fGradeModifier >= 7) ? "+" :
                (fGradeModifier >= 4)? "" : "-";

                //concatenate letter grade and modifier
                sLetterGrade = sAlphaGrade + sAlphaModifier;

            } // end if
            else {
                // sLetterGrade still needs to get a value
                sLetterGrade = sAlphaGrade;
            }


            String sResults =    sEmail  + "\n" +
            // sMessage has been commented out so the program will compile and run
            // Uncomment it if you declare it and give it a value somewhere.
            // sMessage + "\n" +
            "your test score is: " + fGrade + "\n" + 
            "your letter grade is: " + sLetterGrade;


            // Assuming sOutput was meant to mean sResults
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sResults,"Email and Grade",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        } //end convertGrades
    } //end class Email
```

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I am taking a look at this again this afternoon.